# Getting PoolAcquireTimeoutException : Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 45000ms

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am using spring cloud gateway sometimes i see poolconnectionTimeoutexception:

```
ERROR 1 --- [    parallel-29] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [5f4fbedf]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/"

reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquireTimeoutException: Pool#acquire(Duration) has been pending for more than the configured timeout of 45000ms
    at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.run(AbstractPool.java:413) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.20.jar!/:1.0.20]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ com.gateway.apigateway.config.CorsConfig$$Lambda$628/0x0000000801134060 [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint â‡¢ HTTP GET "/" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.run(AbstractPool.java:413) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.20.jar!/:1.0.20]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.19.jar!/:3.4.19]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.19.jar!/:3.4.19]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

exception should not occur